# igTree calling igTree('select', x) to set focus. Node x obtained via igTree('nodeByIndex'...) get an error

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, infragistics, ignite-ui, igtree

In javascript, I'm trying to set the focus (selected) node in an igTree using the igTree('select', node) method.  When I use a node obtained from an event (such as Changing) this select method works fine.

In this case, though, I'm trying to use one of the igTree methods to get the node I'm passing to igTree('select' ...).

I can see that the node object I'm getting is the correct one. The path is "2_3", which is correct. However, the select is throwing an error:

Uncaught TypeError: node.attr is not a function

I'm using knockout.js bindings to create the tree. The bindings are two levels deep and the binding structure at each level is identical.

Using the latest version of IgniteUI and using ui.igTree object.

Infragistics seems to be having problems with their forums.

Any idea why this would not work?

Comment: OK, I'm going to answer my own question.  The key is that when you get back an element from igTree('nodeByIndex', ...) this it NOT a legal argument for igTree('select', arg).  You have to run this through igTree('nodeFromElement', nodeByIndex), but this is STILL not a legal argument for igTree('select', arg).  You have to use the .element member of that returned node so igTree('select', nodeFromElement.element) and THAT will work.

Answer (score 0):

The select method takes a jQuery element as a parameter. The node object returned by `nodeByIndex` contains the element in it, so you need to call the method like this:

```
var node = $('#tree').igTree('nodeByIndex', index);
$('#tree').igTree('select', node.element);
```

If you use the `nodeByPath` method you will get a jQuery element directly instead of a node object.

```
var node = $('#tree').igTree('nodeByPath', "2_3");
$('#tree').igTree('select', node);
```